# Neither switchClass nor addClass().removeClass() methods working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css-transitions, animate.css

I feel like I'm doing this exactly the way I've read online. I actually *can* get toggleClass to work in a limited way ([Toggle sort-of success but not really](http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/Experiments/fxPerspectiveMultiToggle.php)), but the problems with that method have led me to try **switchClass** and **add/removeClass** instead. But... neither does anything when I click the "button".

Yes, I do have jQuery installed in the same directory (hence toggleClass sort of working sometimes).

Here is the page: [Switch fail](http://www.hauntedbuckscounty.com/Experiments/fxPerspectiveSingleSwitch.php)

I'll try to provide the code below (bear with me, it's my first time posting here):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Haunted Bucks County (HBC)</title>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animate-shadow.js"></script>
<style><link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></style>

<style>
#Solar.SolarDegree0 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:orange;
    margin:0px 0px 0px 100px;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 0deg );
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
}
#Solar.SolarDegree45 {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:0px 0px 0px -250px;
    transform: perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg );
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms;
}
</style>
</head>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">

<div id="Solar" class="SolarDegree0" style="height:250px; width:450px;">

</div>



<div id="Weather" style="height:50px; width:150px; background-color:red; margin:0px 0px 0px 100px; position: absolute; top:250px;">

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    $("#Weather").click(function() {
        $("#Solar").toggleClass("SolarDegree45");
    });
    */
    $("#Weather").click(function() {
        /*$("#Solar").switchClass("SolarDegree0", "SolarDegree45");*/
        ("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegree45").removeClass("SolarDegree0");
        /*("#Solar").css({'width': '200px'});*/
    });


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Question would be easier to work with if you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know what jsFiddle is at the moment, but I will take a look when I have the chance. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.toggleClass()` with two classes as parameter which needs to be switched:

```
$("#Solar").toggleClass("SolarDegree45 SolarDegree0");
```

first class in `.toggleClass()` method should be the one that already exists in element. which is `SolarDegree45` in your case.

Comment: Ah, great info. I will experiment with that! On the switch and add/remove methods, which I may look to for alternatives... any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you are missing  jquery selector `$` in addclass and removeclass. also switching will not work for addclass and removeclass

Comment: Cool, that fixed add/remove method! I assume that to add/remove more than one class at a time, I would simply separate them with spaces?

Comment: As for the switch method... Shouldn't it work if I comment out the add/remove method? When I comment out add/remove, then un-comment the switch, switch still doesn't work. And on that one, I did have the jQuery selector $... any ideas? I apologize, I'm very new to this... it's possible I've just misunderstood the switch method altogether.

Comment: you should use toggleClass instead of switchclass. exactly the way i mentioned in the solution.

Comment: I will definitely experiment with your toggle solution. However, as this becomes more complex, I'm wondering if add/remove might be better suited (toggle seems dualistic, though I may just not have a good enough grasp on it yet)? No need to respond if the discussion is becoming too protracted, I'm just posing the question for other readers to contemplate possible differences between methods.

Comment: you would have to write the code that have if else condition for determining which class needs to be added and which needs to be removed. which toggleClass does in one line.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `$` on `("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegree45").removeClass("SolarDegree0");`

Should be

```
$("#Solar").addClass("SolarDegree45").removeClass("SolarDegree0");
```

You can also try

```
$("#Weather").click(function() {
    $("#Solar").toggleClass("SolarDegree45 SolarDegree0");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I ultimately want 3 buttons to produce one arrangement each, for 3 divs. If it's already arranged the way "assigned" to a button, I wouldn't want it to toggle, right? And could toggle handle this scenario anyway? I may be confused here. If toggle is more versatile than I feel like it is, I would definitely like to understand better. (fyi: I would ^ your response, but I don't have enough cred yet, apparently)